# Org Table Sum IFs

Tags: org-mode, table

I have two tables, 'tbl1', where I keep adding entries, and 'tbl2' where i get the totals.
What I'm looking for, is to ADD up all values that match both the 1st row and 1st column ,returning empty or zero when there's no match

```
#+NAME: tbl2
|  /                   |    1 |   2 |     3 |   4 | TOTAL |
|----------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+-------|
| BB                   |      |     |       |     |       |
| CH                   |      |     |       |     |       |
| M                    | 435  |     |       |     |  435  |
| N                    |      | 350 |       |     |  350  |
| G                    | 565  |     |       |     |  565  |
| XL                   |      | 275 |       |     |  275  |
| SP                   |      |     |       |     |       |
| P                    |      |     |       |     |       |
| GG                   |      |     |       |     |       |
|----------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+-------|
| TOTAL                | 1000 | 625 |       |     |       |
#+TBLFM: $2='(apply '+ (org-lookup-all @<$2 '(remote(tbl1, @I$2..@>$2)) '(remote(tbl1, @I$4..@>$4))));L


#+NAME: tbl1
|            |        |           |            |
|------------+--------+-----------+------------|
| 2024-01-25 |      1 | M         |        175 |
| 2024-01-25 |      1 | G         |        250 |
| 2024-01-25 |      2 | N         |        175 |
| 2024-01-25 |      2 | XL        |        100 |
| 2024-01-24 |      1 | M         |        175 |
| 2024-01-24 |      1 | G         |        175 |
| 2024-01-24 |      2 | N         |        175 |
| 2024-01-24 |      2 | XL        |        175 |
| 2024-01-26 |      1 | M         |         85 |
| 2024-01-26 |      1 | G         |        140 |
```

Comment: Got a solution based on this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33566/conditional-evaluation-of-org-mode-tables/33571#33571  where i added a second condition to the lambda function like so #+TBLFM: @4$2='(apply #'+ (cl-mapcar (lambda (qua cam cat) (if (and (eq cam '@<$2) (eq cat '@4$<)) qua 0)) '(remote(entrada, @I$4..@>$4)) '(remote(entrada, @I$2..@>$2)) '(remote(entrada, @I$3..@>$3))));L   OH, Forgat to say i used ChatGPT for some checking, and Thank you Drew for formatting